# Facebook Graph API error: Application must be whitelisted or users must be testers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group, facebook-game-groups

> Applications can invite users to a group by issuing a POST request to /GROUP_ID/members/USER_ID with an app access_token.

When I do this with a user who is a tester everything works fine.
If I try this with a non tester i get the error message:

> (#3) Application must be whitelisted or users must be testers.

Anyone an idea what this means? 
I cannot find this error message anywhere.

Regards,
Roy

Answer (score 2):

I think your application is proably in sandbox mode.
Try to change this in *[app settings](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)*, i think this would help.

Best regards

Chris

Comment: App is not in sandbox mode. If I put the app in sandbox mode I get the same error message.

Comment: This is not a bad suggestion, just because it doesn't answer the OP's problem doesn't mean it should be downvoted

Answer (score 0):

Is your app a game? Is the group you're trying to add to owned by your app?

Check the [App And Game Groups](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/concepts/app-game-groups/) documentation - the docs mention restrictions on use of the API that you may not be aware of

{edit} you said your app isn't a game - see this note from the top of the docs:

> While in beta, only games that are in the App Center will have Game
>   Groups enabled. For development purposes, the Game Groups API will
>   work for application admins, developers, testers and test users.

Comment: The first grey bit in my question is from the group documentation. so i thought this would work.

Comment: the app created the group. How can i see if the group is owned by the app?

Comment: [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) this does not mention limitations on inviting members. thanks allready for your time.